# How to round off the float value to nearest decimal value?

Tags: c, decimal

Given:

```
double value = -59.5968;
```

the code must display the value as 60:

```
sprintf(array, "%.0f", value);
```

This works except when 0 is displayed as -0 for the value -0.3959; it should just display 0 for -0.3959.

Can you suggest some ways to overcome this?

The code has to meet the [MISRA standard](http://www.misra.org.uk/Publications/tabid/57/Default.aspx#label-c3); it's for use in an automotive context.

Comment: What language are you using?  Probably should have at least tagged that...i'm guessing c/c++, but can't really tell for certain.

Comment: Declared value as float 32

Answer (score 0):

The C99 and C11 standards provide a plethora of functions related to rounding floating point quantities, including:

- [`ceil()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ceil.html)
- [`floor()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/floor.html)
- [`nearbyint()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nearbyint.html)
- [`rint()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rint.html)
  and [`lrint()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lrint.html)
- [`round()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/round.html)
  and [`lround()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lround.html)
- [`trunc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/trunc.html)

Of these, `round()`, `rint()` and `nearbyint()` are the ones you're likely to be looking for.

Comment: Then you need to read the MISRA standard, and you need to say so in the question because you're working with your hands tied behind your back.